# How to use preg_replace to replace texts outside double single-quote?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a text file like this:

```
ip_rule '100 120 16.54'
qos_rule '8074 4462'
info 'Updated on 2015'
```

And I want that text to be like this:

```
ip_rule='100 120 16.54'
qos_rule='8074 4462'
info='Updated on 2015'
```

So it only replaces the spaces outside of `''` and change them to the equal sign `=`. How can I do that with PHP, I've tried replacing them with `str_replace` but it replaces the entire spaces.

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Comment: read the file line by line and replace only the first space occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to skip a rule. For example in your current example this will skip anything in single quotes, then find any horizontal spaces (if there can be multiple and it should only be replaced with one `=`s use the `+` quantifier):

```
'.*?'(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\h
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/umaQdY/1

PHP Usage:

```
echo preg_replace("/'.*?'(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\h/", '=', "ip_rule '100 120 16.54'
qos_rule '8074 4462'
info 'Updated on 2015'");
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/663922

You can read more about this here, http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#pcrevariation.

Comment: I feel this may be a little overkill in this particular case. Just `preg_replace("/^(\S+)\s+(.*)$/m","$1=$2",$input)` will do.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yea, that'd be more efficient. I'm not sure if there are other formats the OP has. My solution was to solve `texts outside double single-quote`. If this it is this static format could just use `str_replace(" '", "='", $string);`.